# JavaScript date picker

Tags: javascript

In my PHP form I have used two inputs for date

- Arrival Date and
- Departure Date.

Currently when we select the Date Icon then it will pop up showing CURRENT DATE AND MONTH.

What I want is if the user selects the arrival date and after that the user selects the Departure Date then the DATE ICON should be pop up based on Arrival date.

For Example -- In arrival date suppose I have selected the month JULY and date is 8 so when we click on date icon of Departure date then it should defaults to the month JULY and date 8.

Thus it would be so much more user friendly if the second drop down box was formatted this way.

Comment: What I want is if the user selects the arrival date and after that the user selects the Departure Date then the DATE ICON should be pop up based on Arrival date.

For Example -- In arrival date suppose I have selected the month JULY and date is 8 so when we click on date icon of Departure date then it should defaults to the month JULY and date 8.

Thus it would be so much more user friendly if the second drop down box was formatted this way.

Comment: My question starts from 3rd paragraph...pls help me

Comment: which date picker do you use? jQuery? To solve your problem I think you can use javascript to set the value of Departure Date the same as Arrive Date using onTextChange for Arrive Date input. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

make this 
on first datefield  write onchange="somefunc()"

```
function somefunc()
{
 document.getElementById('Departure').value= document.getElementById(Arrival).value;
}
```

after that back to your calander 
I use 
http://www.dynarch.com/projects/calendar/
try with it

Comment: Its not working----This is what I have done-----<div class="inputdiv">
           <input type="text"  name="strArrDate" id="strArrDate" class="field" value="Arrival Date"  onchange="somefunc();"/>
          <a href="#" ><img src="img.jpg" onclick="DtPk('strArrDate');return false;"/></a>
           <input name="strDepDate" id="strDepDate" type="text" class="field" value="Departure Date" />
         </div>
        -And here is the Script <script type="text/javascript">
 
function somefunc() { 
document.getElementById('strDepDate').value= document.getElementById('strArrDate').value; 
}

</script>

Comment: Now I have solved it by using onblur() instead of onchange..Thanks a LOT :)

Answer (score 0):

Its been solved it by using onblur() instead of onchange..Thanks a LOT :) –